# How do I convert UTF-8 to/from UTF-16 in C?

Tags: c

Is there a library available, or do I need to design/code my own?

The target platform is very old and the compiler does not provide `wchar_t`.

No library is allowed, so plain C and headers will be appropriate.

Comment: Hmm "Is there a library available" and then "No library is allowed"... perhaps a slight contradiction in terms?

Answer (score 0):

Also you can try `iconv()`. On some platform it's part of the C runtime.

Comment: Thanks. Don't have this on our platform. We will be migrating to new platform soon and will try this one if i have no solution by then